# Native header and footer with inAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ace-plugin

Still trying to wrap my head around Ace.

We have an inAppBrowser opening "over" the webview. Would we be able to add a native header and footer and have the inAppBrowser take up the space in the middle using Ace?

Any examples that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin? With Ace, there is a way to write JavaScript to manipulate any native UI objects and attach new ones (like headers and footers), although the exact approach depends on how cordova-plugin-inappbrowser presents its native UI. I'm intrigued by this question, so I'll do some research. And I bet there's something we can do to Ace to make interacting with native UI injected by other plugins easier.

Alternatively, you could navigate to a new native page with a header, footer, and a separate WebView control. But then, you'd be responsible for adding your own back/forward/done buttons, so perhaps that's not the best way to go.

**UPDATE**: I've posted a new sample that accomplishes this: https://github.com/Microsoft/ace/tree/master/examples/WithOtherPlugins/InAppBrowser

The relevant case is the "dialog" one. Note that Page-level things like navigation headers and menu bars aren't supported yet on modal dialogs, but this surrounds the other plugin's native UI with native buttons in a grid. I'll be posting a writeup about this tomorrow and I'll update this answer when I do. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Adam! My team is very excited about Ace! Yes, I am referring to the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. The inAppBrowser has several advantages over moving to another native page. I can add handlers in the main WebView to inAppBrowser events.